# Read a value from JSON Array without entity

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, botframework

I need to access the 2.2.10.60 and "bank overdrafts...." value from the following array --
[image]

May I ask about how to get it? 
Here with my code.

```
     var json=chunk.toString();      
       var obj = JSON.parse(json);
       session.send(obj.clauses[0]);
 console.log(obj.clauses[0]);
```

But I can't get the value of "2.3.10.60" and "Bank overdrafts....".
and the inside the "clauses" array will always change.

**I had Solved by my own:**

```
var graph = JSON.parse(json);
       for(var i=0;i<graph.clauses.length;i++){
           var obj=graph.clauses[i];
          console.log(obj);
           var clause_id;
           var clause_text;

           for(var key in obj)
           {
               clause_id=key;
               clause_text=obj[key].toString();
               session.send(clause_id+"<br>"+clause_text);
           }
       }
```

Comment: Please add the content as a code instead of using images.

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to create an answer, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: @VLAZ I want to read the JSONArray value from "clauses" , "2.3.1.60" & "Bank Overdrafts..."

Comment: @EngSoonCheah sure, but that doesn't really tell me anything. You can do `obj.clauses[0]`, yet it seems that's insufficient. Why is that?

Comment: That's a terrible data structure. I hope you can change it.

Comment: That solution is no where close to the described question. :

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and check if the wanted property exist in the object. Then take the object and use an property accessor for the result.

```
key = '2.2.10.60'
result = clauses.find(object => key in object)[key];
```

If you are not sure about if the array does not contain any object with this key, take an default object or check in advance if `find` returns a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value (like an object), take this

```
var key = '2.2.10.60'
    result,
    temp = clauses.find(object => key in object);

if (temp) {
    result = temp[key];
}
```

For a dynamic approach, you could take a variable for the wanted key.

---

For getting just the first entry of the object, you could take the entries of index zero. This approach assumes, theat only one key/value pair exists in the object.

```
var [key, value] = Object.entries(object.clauses[0])[0];
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                         target by destructuring an array
//                                ^^^^^^                 source
//                                       ^^^^^^^         property
//                                              ^^^      index/the first one
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^     get all key/value pairs of object
//                                                  ^^^  take the first pair only
```

Comment: Apparently the clauses always change? At least that's what OP commented on my answer, but I don't really get what OP means by that. In any case, this is a bit verbose for what you're trying to accomplish, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @Baruch, op could take a variable. it a standard tool for dynamic content. please see edit.

Comment: The key is always change.

Comment: what is changing?

Comment: I assumed the OP just wants to pick the key and value of the first object, not search the array by any specific key. So something like `key = Object.keys(obj.clauses[0])[0]` and `obj.clauses[0][key]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Array.find()` method and verify if the object keys have the value you need.

```js
clauses.find(object => Object.keys(object).includes('2.2.10.60'))
```

This will return an array of the first object whose keys include '2.2.10.60'

Comment: But the clauses always change.

Comment: @EngSoonCheah You should've said taht in your question, eh? What do you mean by they always change? What changes?

Comment: @EngSoonCheah So, use another key name instead of `2.2.10.60`?

Comment: @EngSoonCheah - You haven't explained what you want to do. From context, it seems like you want to access the first element in the array (element by index). But in your question you asking how to get the element containing "2.3.10.60" specifically (element by value). If you want to get the element by index then how do you know which index contains the information you want? If you want to get the element by value then how do you know what value you're looking for? How does this JSON work, where does it come from, and what are you trying to do with it?